# Access outside variable in loop from Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, closures

See:

```
for (var i in this.items) {
    var item = this.items[i];
    $("#showcasenav").append("<li id=\"showcasebutton_"+item.id+"\"><img src=\"/images/showcase/icon-"+item.id+".png\" /></li>");
    $("#showcasebutton_"+item.id).click(function() {
        alert(item.id);
        self.switchto(item.id);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the alerted item.id is always the id of the last item in the array (this.items). How to solve?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem you have here is that the variable `item` changes with each loop.  When you are referencing `item` at some later point, the last value it held is used.  You can use a technique called a [closure](http://matthew-marksbury.blogspot.com/2008/12/javascript-closures-and-scope.html) (essentially a function that returns a function) to quickly scope the variable differently.

```
    for (var i in this.items) {
            var item = this.items[i];
            $("#showcasenav").append("<li id=\"showcasebutton_"+item.id+"\"><img src=\"/images/showcase/icon-"+item.id+".png\" /></li>");
            $("#showcasebutton_"+item.id).click( 
                // create an anonymous function that will scope "item"
                (function(item) {
                   // that returns our function 
                   return function() {
                    alert(item.id);
                    self.switchto(item.id);
                   };
                })(item) // immediately call it with "item"
            );
    }
```

A side note - I see that you have jQuery here.  It has a helper function [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) that can be used with arrays, and can be a shortcut for simple for/each loops.  Because of the way the scoping works in this call - you wont need to use a closure  because "item" is already the parameter of the function when it was called, not stored in a `var` in the parent function's scope, like was true in your example.

```
$.each(this.items,function(i, item) {
  $("#showcasenav").append("<li id=\"showcasebutton_"+item.id+"\"><img src=\"/images/showcase/icon-"+item.id+".png\" /></li>");
  $("#showcasebutton_"+item.id).click(function() {
    alert(item.id);
    self.switchto(item.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: Found a more elegant solution for you after the fact - check out the advantage of using `$.each()`

Comment: Thank you! I just spend a while trying to create a closure to use a local variable inside my click callback.  The tricky part for me removing the parameters from the function being returned.

Answer (score 4):

The other way to approach this is to make sure the `= items[i]` business is effectively done by calling a function.  In shorthand, this:

```
for (var i in this.items) {
    (function(item) {
        $("#showcasenav").append("<li id=\"showcasebutton_"+item.id+"\"><img src=\"/images/showcase/icon-"+item.id+".png\" /></li>");
        $("#showcasebutton_"+item.id).click(function() {
            alert(item.id);
            self.switchto(item.id);
        });
    })(this.items[i]);
}
```

The anonymous function there is a bit messy, making it rather preferable to have a not-so-anonymous one around for the purpose, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript closures store references to their variables, so all of your onclick handlers are using the same variable.

You need to capture the variable in an intermediate function, like this:

```
function buildClickHandler(pageNumber) {
    return function()  {    //Create and return a new function
        alert(item.id);
        self.switchto(item.id);
    }
}
```

Then, use that function to create `click` handlers, like this:

```
for (var i in this.items) {
    var item = this.items[i];
    $("#showcasenav").append("<li id=\"showcasebutton_"+item.id+"\"><img src=\"/images/showcase/icon-"+item.id+".png\" /></li>");

    $("#showcasebutton_"+item.id).click(buildClickHandler(item));
}
```

Each call to `buildClickHandler` creates a separate closure that has its own variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this loop

```
for (var i=0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
  this.items[i]
};
```

Comment: No, the loop is fine. The problem is that every added list item sees the same "item.id" in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

I know very well that this is an old post, but it seems that the genious people designing jQuery (which I figured you must be using) have made the most optimal solution to your problem, as I understand it.

In the new 1.4 version of the library, [they have added the jQuery.proxy() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). This enables you to efficiently modify the context/scope of the function you are calling - done the jQuery way, which ensures that you can stop using techniques that could potentially mess up things.