# jQuery input value undefined after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

Anyone that can help me out will be very much appreciated. I seem to have got myself into a bit of a kerfuffle.

I'm trying to assign response data - retrieved from an AJAX request using the jquery.autocomplete plugin - to an input element. I can get the response data back fine, but when I try and insert it into the 'value' attribute, nothing happens!

```
$('#btnPopulate').click(function() {
if ($('#list_length').val() != '') {
    var length = $('#list_length').val();
    var row='';
    for (var i=0; i <= length; i++) {
        row="<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td><input name='data[CompanyRanking]["+i+
         "][company_id]' id='CompanyRanking"+i+
         "CompanyId' value='1'></td><input type='hidden' name='data[CompanyRanking]["+i+
         "][ranking]' id='CompanyRanking"+i+"Ranking' value='"+i+"'></tr>";
        $('#ranking_table').append(row);
        $("CompanyRanking"+i+"CompanyId").autocomplete({ 
            serviceUrl:'/backend/companies/search',
            minChars:2, 
            delimiter: null, // regex or character
            maxHeight:400,
            width:300,
            deferRequestBy: 50, //miliseconds
            // callback function:
            onSelect: function(value, data){ 
                alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); 
                                $('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId').val(data);
                alert('val: '+
                             $('#CompanyRanking'+i+
                             'CompanyId').val() + 'object?: '+
                             $('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId'));
               }
        });
            };
    //$('#btnPopulate').ac;
    } else {
    alert('You must first specify how many companies are in the list.');
};
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I've narrowed down the source of this error a bit more. It seems that the loop variable 'i' isn't being used correctly within the 'onSelect' function. This function is being called when the user inputs some data into the input field and so 'i' is set to the maximum loop count, as opposed to the specific element I'm trying to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem to be a problem of scope. Try creating a closure around the value of `i` inside the loop:

```
onSelect: (function(i) {
    return function(value, data){ 
        $('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId').val(data);
    }
}(i))
```

A better explanation can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure/1331796#1331796):

> The problem you have here is that the
>   variable item changes with each loop.
>   When you are referencing item at some
>   later point, the last value it held is
>   used. You can use a technique called a
>   closure (essentially a function that
>   returns a function) to quickly scope
>   the variable differently.

Comment: THANK YOU! You saved me a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you are trying to alert a text value and not the value itself.

```
alert('val: '+$('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId').text() + 'object?: '+$('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId'));
```

could perhaps be changed to:

```
alert('val: '+$('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId').val() + 'object?: '+$('#CompanyRanking'+i+'CompanyId'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've also tried that. The .val() still returns 'undefined'. I've updated the original post so that it makes more sense.