# Passing values to onclick

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

If I create a whole lot of HTML elements using a loop, like

```
for (i= 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var my_element = document.createElement ("td");
    row.appendChild (my_element);
    my_element.onclick = function () {my_function (i));
}
```

then when the element is clicked, the value of i passed to `my_function` is always 100, regardless of what number element is calling it. I have worked around this by using

```
my_element.id = "something"+i;
my_element.onclick = function (e) {my_function (e.target.id)};
```

(For Internet Explorer, the `target` needs to be `srcElement`, apparently.) I am curious to know whether there is any way to create the function without having to add the ID to the element like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of `i` changes with each iteration of the loop. [You need a closure to capture the value of `i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure/1331796#1331796):

```
(function(i) {
    my_element.onclick = function () {my_function (i)};
}(i))
```

Comment: Your bracketing is wrong but this idea worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a function which builds you a handler function, you can use the new scope which that gives you to ensure that you get the number you want. For example:

```
function BuildHandler (i) { return function () { alert(i); };

for (i= 1; i < 100; i++) {
    var my_element = document.createElement ("td");
    row.appendChild (my_element);
    my_element.onclick = BuildHandler(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I were you I will use Jquery (or prototype or whatever js frameworks that available)

on each elements you should add attributes like myid for example so that when you did on click you can retrive it.

```
for(i=1; i ++ ; i<100){
   var myelement = "<td myid='something"+i+"' class='myTD'></td>" ;
   row.append(myelement);
}

.... 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myTD').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('myid');
     my_function(id);
  });

});
```

I did this trick on my web app :)

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong and misses the point of the question.