# javascript setInterval isnot working?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use "setInterval" to reload a page that contains an embedded googlemaps.

When I use:

```
var marker = createMarker (point, id);
```

the page runs ok (one time). but when I try:

```
var marker = setInterval (function () {createMarker (point, id);}, 5000);
```

to automatically refresh the page, the following error occurs:

```
main.js:686Uncaught TypeError: Object 8 has no method 'initialize
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <!--<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">-->
    <title>Position</title>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key="
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    //<![CDATA[

    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
            );

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        //create map and center it
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

        GDownloadUrl("gen_xml.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var point = new GLatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude"))
            );
            //var marker = createMarker(point, id);
            var marker = setInterval(function(){createMarker(point, id);},5000);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            map.setCenter(point,17);

          }
        });

      }
    }

    function createMarker(point, id) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point, icon);
      var html = "<b>" + id + "</b> <br/>" + point;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <center>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Google Maps 2 and 3 APIs in there. `maps?file=api&v=2` but `google.maps.*` is `v3` i believe.

Answer (score 3):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) returns an integer, not the value that `createMarker()` returns. Use the value returned by `createMarker` **in the `setInterval`** callback.

```
setInterval(function ()
{
    var marker = createMarker(point, id);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    map.setCenter(point, 17);
}, 5000);
```

You may also be seeing the [classic JS function-in-a-loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841247/google-maps-event-listener-only-remembering-final-value-of-variable).