# Re-associate AJAX call with original URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm not sure how to even explain this, which makes it very difficult to search on (especially because I am SURE this is an error in thinking).

I have an array of objects:

```
var a = [
    {
        url: "http://www.discusionboard.com/list-of-boards/", 
        name: "Discussion Board One", 
        threads: []
    },
    {url: "...", name: "...", threads: [] }
]
```

I am looping through these objects, downloading each page, and then *trying* to add the threads back to the original object.

```
for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    jQuery.get(a[i].url, function(result, status, xhr) {
        /* result is list of threads separated by "[SPLIT]" */
        a[i].threads = result.split("[SPLIT]")
    });
}
```

My issue, then, is that the "i" in a[i].threads is undefined. I can't find a way to pass it into the function, and that makes me think I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding a core concept here.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm happy to read myself, if someone could just give me an idea of what I should look for. As you can see by my title, I'm having a hard time even describing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Looks like the closure loop problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of the closure loop problem. The callback function you pass to jQuery is executed only *after* the loop has finished (even after the function it is inside of returns a value). Therefore, `a[i]` (to the callback function) will always be the last element of the array. [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) provides the `context` setting to address this problem:

```
for( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: a[i].url,
        context: a[i],
        success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            /* result is list of threads separated by "[SPLIT]" */
            this.threads = result.split("[SPLIT]")
        }
    });
}
```

Note that if you have code afterward that needs to make use of the completed objects, that is also a problem. To address this, you would need to put this outside the callback function:

```
var numRequests = a.length;
```

And this at the end of the callback function:

```
if(!--numRequests) {
    // Do whatever now that all object data has been loaded.
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I just learned about "context" and it does just about everything I need for now, but I see how closure could be a problem in other instances. Thanks for the examples!