# JavaScript for in loop issue

Tags: javascript

i need to get 4 request from the server, i have stored all this 4 urls in this way. for information this is raw url (http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/40.714352/-74.0059731);

```
var nationZone = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime : 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime:'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'

}
```

this is calling my getTime.php and retrieving the result.

for that, i created this for in loop, but this prints only one time intead of 4 times? how can i make this to call 4 request ?

```
for(zone in nationZone ){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        zone=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        zone=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    zone.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(zone.readyState==4 && zone.status==200){
            alert(zone.responseText);
        }
    }
    zone.open("GET",nationZone[zone],true);
    zone.send();
}
```

I do not mind using a solution that involves an additional third party library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access outside variable in loop from Javascript closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if your using jQuery, but I doubt about it to work, because cross domain ajax is not allowed.

```
var nationZone = {
    getNewYorkLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=40.7143528&lan=-74.0059731',
    getLondonLocalTime : 'getTime.php?lat=51.5001524&lan=-0.1262362',
    getChennaiLocalTime :  'getTime.php?lat=13.060422&lan=80.249583',
    getBangaloreLocalTime:'getTime.php?lat=12.9715987&lan=77.5945627'

}

$.each(nationZone , function(key, value){
    $.get(value, function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same name for the loop variable and the XHR. Don't do that.

EDIT: Also, this question has the jQuery tag, but you are not using jQuery. Instead of doing your own XHR stuff, use jQuery's ajax implementation through $.ajax or $.get. Also consider using JSONP, if the remote server supports it.

Comment: While this is true, this is not the only problem and changing the name won't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

`zone` variable inside the if/else block is overwriting the `zone` from the for loop. Hence your loop only has one `zone` object to handle by the time it finishes the first iteration.

Use some other var name inside the function. The line :

```
`zone.open("GET",nationZone[zone],true);`
```

should say

```
`newZoneVariable.open("GET", nationZone[zone], true);`
```

where newZoneVariable is the var used inside the loop body.