# Object scope while attaching an event listener in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do something like this:

```
for(int i =0; i< results.length; i++){
    $('ul').append('<li>'+results[i].name+'</li>').bind('click',function(){
        doSomething(results[i]);
    })
}
```

but when the click happens, the object passed to doSomething is undefined. How do I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access outside variable in loop from Javascript closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`results[i]` is only valid variable at the time machine is inside the `for` loop, later on, when event handler is triggered, `result[i]` is undefined.

That's why you need to ensure `results[i]` *gets saved* as variable in context of a function.

```
for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++){
    (function(result) {
        $('<li>'+result.name+'</li>').appendTo($('ul')).bind('click',function(){
            doSomething(result);
        })
    })(results[i]);
}
```

Here's working example http://jsfiddle.net/T9aUq/.

Edit: Actually to make it really work, I had to change the way events are registered - at first, click handler was binded to elements matching $('ul') instead of new li element (since `append()` function of jQuery doesn't return appended element, but rather sticks to previous scope (which  was `ul`).

Comment: I think you're missing braces?
`(function(result) {
...
})(results[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

save your element first!

```
for(var i =0; i< results.length; i++){
    var element = results[i];
    var li = $('<li/>').html(element.name);
    $('ul').append(li);
    li.click(function(){
        doSomething(element);
    });
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on this answer; the issue is that `i` is constantly changing.

Comment: This won't work, because just as `i` changes, so does `element`. See the other answer that addresses the issue with closures.

Comment: Your code is broken. For one, there's typo `int` instead of `var`, for two, the resulting handler would always fire `doSomething` function with last element of results array as argument. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hTBa/

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this same problem recently... Silly is right, however the variables need some form of encapsulation:

```
for(var i =0; i< results.length; i++) doThisFirst(i);
function doThisFirst(index) {
    $('ul').append('<li>'+results[index].name+'</li>').bind('click',function(){
        doSomething(results[index]);
    })
}
```

If that doesn't work... Make sure you don't have a loop inside a loop with the same varname for the index:

```
for (var i = 0; ...) {
    for (var i = 0; ...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not realize WTK had posted the answer for this already.