# How do I get the current value of a button being called from an array to display something from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Trying to get the numerical value of the current button that's being called from an array so I can display an image and description from another array based on bNames array number.

**i** doesn't seem to work.
Trying to get images[i] and descriptions[i] to show based on the numerical value of bNames.

```
var bNames = ["#button01","#button02","#button03"];
var images = ["image01.png","image02.png","image03.png"];
var descriptions = ["And a one","And a two", "And a three"];


for (var i=0; i<bNames.length; i++){
$(bNames[i]).click(function(e) { 
    $("#image").html("<img src=images/" + images[i] + " />");
    $("#desc").html(descriptions[i]);
});
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: using a class would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331769/access-outside-variable-in-loop-from-javascript-closure). Also see [JavaScript loop closures](http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_loop_closures)  for more information. Essentially, you are always using the last value that is held by `i`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for (var i=0; i<bNames.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        $(bNames[index]).click(function(e) { 
            $("#image").html("<img src=images/" + images[index] + " />");
            $("#desc").html(descriptions[index]);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Also from that question, you could do this instead:

```
$.each(bNames, function(i, item) {
    $(item).click(function(e) {
        $("#image").html("<img src=images/" + images[i] + " />");
        $("#desc").html(descriptions[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: Never ever define a function inside a loop...**

**You are in the world of HTML5 *its a revolution*... Use data attributes...**
Heres the solution...

HTML:

```
  <button class="button" data-index="0">Button01</button>
  <button class="button" data-index="1">Button02</button>
  <button class="button" data-index="2">Button03</button>
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var images = ["image01.png","image02.png","image03.png"];
var descriptions = ["And a one","And a two", "And a three"];


$(".button").click(function(){
  var i = $(this).data("index");
  $("#image").html("<img src=images/" + images[i] + " />");
  $("#desc").html(descriptions[i]);
});
```